# Argumentos barplot

Tags: r, barplot

Fiz um gráfico com a função barplot, e preciso mudar o angulo do texto no eixo X, pois as palavras são longas. Sei que para colocá-las verticalmente usá-se las=2, mas quero que elas fiquem inclinadas (um angulo de 45°). Como faço?

Este foi o script que usei:

```
barplot(prop.sentenca [ ,1], beside = T, 
main = "Proporção de aplicação do imperativo com morfologia de indicativo \n por Sentença em Feira de Santana-BA", names.arg = c("correr","sair", "viajar", "cozinhar", "comprar", "arrumar"),
ylim = c(0,90), ylab = "Proporção do imperativo com morfologia de indicativo", 
xlab = "Sentença", col = c("deepskyblue"),las=2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Para rotacionar você terá que usar o comando `text` para criar o eixo X. Na função `text` existe o argumento `srt` para indicar os graus da rotação. Inclua também o argumento `xaxt = "n"` no comando do `barplot` para não criar o mesmo (eixo X) duas vezes.

Segue abaixo um código que encontrei com uma pesquisa rápida no Google.

```
labels <- month.name[1:12]
mp <- barplot(1:12, xaxt = "n", axisnames = FALSE)
text(mp, par("usr")[3], labels = labels, srt = 45, adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex=.9)
```